# How to display earliest date from user input?

Tags: c, loops

I'm having a hard time finding earliest date from user input of a date format mm/dd/yy. 
I did wrote a solution for printing greater date, but lowest date is always showing as 0/0/0 because I am breaking the while loop if /0/0/0 is typed.

The code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  int month, day, year, earliestDay = 0, earliestMonth = 0 , earliestYear=0;


 printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): ");
 scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

while (day && month && year !=0){

   printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);

    if ( earliestDay <= day)
        earliestDay = day;

    if (earliestMonth <= month)
        earliestMonth = month;

    if (earliestYear <= year)
    earliestYear = year;

}
printf("%d/%d/%d is the greatest date!\n", earliestMonth, earliestDay, earliestYear);

}
```

I would appreciate if anyone can explain to me how can I print the lowest.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, the simplest fix would be to initialise your variables to a large number (int max, say).

Comment: and your comparison is backwards. Do you want earliest or latest date? Your `printf` says `greatest` but your variables are `earliest`

Comment: Use `while(1)` and after taking input check if any of them is `0` and break out of the loop.This way you won't process the `0` valued data.Plus i don't think the comparison you are using will give you earliest date.You are breaking the date and just storing the earliest day,month,year separately.

Comment: "while (day && month && year !=0){" shoud be "while (day != 0 && month !=0 && year !=0){". If you want to find min value, you need to set the biggest value for those var when init instead of 0. For EX: "earliestDay = 0, earliestMonth = 0 , earliestYear=0;" should be "earliestDay = 32, earliestMonth = 13 , earliestYear=3000;"

Comment: Change `while (day && month && year !=0)` to `while (1)` and add `if(day == 0&& month == 0 && year == 0)break;` after `scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);`

Comment: none of your solutions seems to work. Perhaps I am not getting it clearly :(

Answer (score 1):

As @RJFalconer says, you need to properly initialize things.

Also, if your "greatest date" solution used similar logic to this, I don't think you tested it very well: you can't treat the year, month and day independently.  Following your logic, if `01/30/99` and `12/01/50` were entered, you'd report `12/30/99` as the greatest date, when it isn't either of the entered dates!  Instead, you need logic like:

```
day1 < day2 IF day1.year < day2.year OR 
              (day1.year==day2.year AND (day1.month < day2.month OR 
                                        (day1.month==day2.month AND day1.day < day2.day)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way of searching for a min/max value in a loop is

```
#include <limits.h>

int earliestDay = INT_MAX;
while (...) {
  earliestDay = min(earliestDay, day);
}
```

or

```
#include <limits.h>

int latestDay = INT_MIN;
while (...) {
  latestDay = max(latestDay, day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After consulting replies from you all I think I found the right way to do it. Please review one more time and see if its alright, even thou I tested it and it works.

The edited code is :

```
int main(){
    int month1, day1, year1, day2, month2 = 0, year2 = 0, earliestDay = 32, earliestMonth = 13 , earliestYear=3000;


    printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month1, &day1, &year1);

    while (1){

        printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): ");
        scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month2, &day2, &year2);

        if((day1 ==0 && month1 && year1 ==0) || (day2 == 0 && month2== 0 && year2 ==0))
           break;

        if ( day1 < day2)
            earliestDay = day1;

        if (month1 < month2)
            earliestMonth = month1;

        if (year1 <= year2)
            earliestYear = year1;

    }
    printf("%d/%d/%d is the earliest date!\n", earliestMonth, earliestDay, earliestYear);
}
```